# How to make existing images into paperclip images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Before using paperclip with rails, I wrote my own upload script with which I uploaded a batch of images and assigned to their respective objects. But now i need to switch all the images to  be paperclip friendly.

Is there a way to pass images to paperclip without using a form?

```
Image.all.each do |image|
  image[:file] = image.filename
  image.save
end
```

something along the lines where i can iterate through a list of Image objects and reassign the image file as a paperclip attachment. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given `file` is the name of your paperclip object, I'd do something like:

```
Image.all.each do |image|
 image.file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/path_to_images/#{image.filename}")
 image.save
end
```

Comment: It works but will duplicate the file, any better ways?

Comment: Duplicate images? Your source folder isnt supposed tobe in your Rails app

Comment: Okay, I got it. My source folder is in my Rails app lol. Thank you.